A contradiction against the statement that all bonds in benzene are of equal length
According to quantum mechanics when an electron is observed its wavefunction collapses into an eigenstate, doesn't that mean that when we observe a molecule that participates in resonance, its resonance hybrid collapses into one of its canonical forms when we observe it? And therefore doesn't this mean that when we measure the bond lengths of a molecule that participates in resonance, say benzene, we observe that not all are of equal length? This contradicts the fact that when we experimentally measure the carbon-carbon bond lengths of benzene we observe that all are of equal length. What is the reason as to why this contradiction appears?

The concept of delocalized electrons describes the structure better than the idea of resonance.

The electrons may be delocalized but on measurement they must collapse into a single state....

The experimental fact is that all bond lengths are equal so any theory or ideas that suggests otherwise must be wrong. Experiment is always the best test.

This quantum idea of your may be the wackiest thing I've seen here in a good while.

The problem with your claim is that it confuses one model of how to explain the structure of benzene with an entirely different model. resonance structures are not "real" observable states but a simple model that tries to use simple theories of two-electron bonds to explain structures better explained by more complex quantum mechanical models using molecular orbitals where electrons spread over many atoms/bonds.

@Mithoron What do you mean by wacky? Could you specify where I am wrong.

@matt_black The entire purpose of a new theory is to cover up the faults of the old one while also being able to explain the experimental results the old theory could. As such quantum theory, being a new theory, must be able to explain resonance.

@mayo Quantum theory doesn't need to explain resonance. It has a perfectly good model of electron orbitals that allow them to spread over more than two atoms. This explains the observed properties of benzene. Resonance is an alternative way from a totally different theory to explain the same thing. So quantum theory does not need to "explain" a feature from a different theory.

Well, do you think Schrödinger cats exist too? Nuclei are not delocalised, electrons are.

What you observe is not an electron as a whole, but some specific physical quantity (an observable). Different observables correspond to different sets of eigenstates (unless they are simultaneously observable).
In a classic example, for a free electron the eigenstates of momentum are $e^{ip_0x/\hbar}$, which is a wave spread all the way to infinity in all directions. In other words, the momentum is known exactly, but the position is not known at all. On the other hand, the eigenstates of position are $\delta(x-x_0)$, which corresponds to known position and unknown momentum, much like that joke about Heisenberg stopped by a traffic cop for speeding. ("Do you know how fast you've been driving? - No, but I know where I am!")
Same thing here. What we usually observe is energy. The eigenfunctions of energy are those delocalized orbitals that you hear about all the time. As for the position of one electron, that's a stupid thing; there is no point in knowing it at all. To pinpoint it, you'll have to hit the system hard enough to destroy the molecule and quite a few other molecules, and then you'll be left with a useless knowledge ("A second ago the electron was right there, in the molecule... Wait! Where is my molecule?")
So it goes.

So when we measure the energy of the bonds, the position does not collapse because energy and position are not simultaneously observable, thus when we measure energy of each bond we find that all bonds are of equal energy. How about when we measure length of the bond? What are we actually measuring there, and does that measurement collapse the position of the electron?

Bond lengths have little to do with electrons. What we measure here is atomic positions. A nucleus is thousands of times heavier than an electron, and hence hardly quantum at all.

Oh OK, so we can ignore their quantum behaviour, nice.
